# Should I set the Enabled property of OLEObject or OLEObject.Object?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a Excel VBA project. In Sheet1 I have a table with 3 command buttons for each row. Outside this table I have another command button named "cbSwap". When I click to this button, it opens a user form. This user form have 2 text boxes and a button. The user form takes two values from two text boxes and transmits them to a function named SwapTwoRange. This function takes the values, uses them as Excel range names. Here's the function:

```
Function SwapTwoRange(val1 As String, val2 As String)
  Dim arr1 As Variant, arr2 As Variant
  Dim Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range

  Set Rng1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("row" & val1)
  Set Rng2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("row" & val2)

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  arr1 = Rng1.Value
  arr2 = Rng2.Value
  Rng1.Value = arr2
  Rng2.Value = arr1
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

  'No problem occured until here.

  If (WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rng1) = 0) Then
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects("cbStartRow" & val1).Object.Enabled = True
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects("cbEndRow" & val1).Object.Enabled = False
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects("cbClearRow" & val1).Object.Enabled = False
  Else
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects("cbStartRow" & val1).Object.Enabled = False
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects("cbEndRow" & val1).Object.Enabled = True
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects("cbClearRow" & val1).Object.Enabled = True
  End If

  If (WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rng2) = 0) Then
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects("cbStartRow" & val2).Object.Enabled = True
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects("cbEndRow" & val2).Object.Enabled = False
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects("cbClearRow" & val2).Object.Enabled = False
  Else
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects("cbStartRow" & val2).Object.Enabled = False
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects("cbEndRow" & val2).Object.Enabled = True
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects("cbClearRow" & val2).Object.Enabled = True
  End If
End Function
```

*cbStartRow*, *cbEndRow* and *cbClearRow* are the command buttons in the table rows in Sheet1. When if block executes, they seem as they are enabled/disabled as I want. But when I select (for example) a **disabled** command button, and look at its properties, its **Enabled** property is **True**. And the program doesn't work as I want. I must refer to command buttons names with the values entered to text boxes (for example if textbox1's value is "1" , the first if-else block will change cbStartRow1, cbEndRow1 and cbClearRow1's Enabled property.)

How can I do it without this problem? I have been searching for a solution in internet forums for last 8 days, but I couldn't find a correct solution. Please help. Thanks anyway.

Comment: What are the values of `val1 As String` and `val2 As String`?

Comment: val1 and val2 are the variables taken from the user form text boxes. The user form has two text boxes. Each of them represent a row in the table in Sheet1. User form takes values from user so it can understand which rows will be swapped. For example; if user enter "1" for textbox1 and "3" for textbox2 and click the button, SwapTwoRange function will be called. The function will take these two values and transact everything on the two rows (row1 and row3; and the buttons in these two rows.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've only used `OLEObject.Object` with 3rd-party ActiveX controls where VBA wouldn't know what the properties where.

So, please can you try and just refer to the `OLEObject` and not the `OLEObject.Object`. Then `Enabled` property acutally belongs to the `OLEObject` - you can check [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838421.aspx).

Your code would be, for example:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects("cbStartRow" & val1).Enabled = True
```

Not:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects("cbStartRow" & val1).Object.Enabled = True
```

You can try this approach with a smaller example. Just create a fresh workbook and insert a single button and then put this in the code module for `Sheet1`. Then run `Test1`:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test1()

    Dim obj As OLEObject

    Set obj = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects(1)

    obj.Enabled = True
    Debug.Print obj.Enabled

    obj.Enabled = False
    Debug.Print obj.Enabled

    obj.Enabled = True
    Debug.Print obj.Enabled

End Sub
```

Which will output:

```
True
False
True
```

Then run `Test2`:

```
Sub Test2()

    Dim obj As OLEObject

    Set obj = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects(1)

    obj.Object.Enabled = True
    Debug.Print obj.Enabled

    obj.Object.Enabled = False
    Debug.Print obj.Enabled

    obj.Object.Enabled = True
    Debug.Print obj.Enabled

End Sub
```

Which will output:

```
True
True
True
```

Comment: Yes! This made the magic, and it worked perfectly! Thanks for your reply. Good works!